# How to track customer email

Tags: customer-session

I want to read customer email and ID for a tracking purpose. My script is as below.

```
<?php
$_email = '';
$_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
if($_customer->getEmail()){
    $_visitorId = $_customer->getId();
    $_email = $_customer->getEmail();

}else{
    $_visitor = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVisitorData();
    $_visitorId = $_visitor['visitor_id'];

}
?>
<!-- Initialize RDK -->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.sfrdk('_setConfig', {
    visitorId: '<?php echo $_visitorId ?>',
    email: '<?php echo $_email ?>'
});
</script>
```

This tracks the customer email in my account page but does not track in the product detail/list pages

Any idea?

Comment: where you put this code?

Comment: in the main body.   /default/template/tracking/global.phtml

Comment: you just put this code in header.phtml file

Comment: Can you please give me location of the file. my header.phtml in Base is not in <head> It's also in the main body.

Comment: template\page\html\header.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You should check if a customer is logged in before getting the email address.
Please check if using the isLoggedIn() function solve you problem

```
    $_email = '';
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
   $_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $_visitorId = $_customer->getId();
    $_email = $_customer->getEmail();
}else{
    $_visitor = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getVisitorData();
    $_visitorId = $_visitor['visitor_id'];
}
```